# Create go back button function like Angry Birds

Tags: android, popupwindow

I'm creating an app in which Go Back Button function like Angry Birds have, I've created popup window, it has close button and other buttons working.

To go back I use:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Write your code here
    initiatePopupWindow();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

I know about `finish()` code that do not go back to pervious Activity 
this code is working when goback Button is pressed. Popup Window opens but instantly it go back to previous Activity.

My Question is : How can stay popup window when go back button is pressed and do not leave to previous activity like Angry Bird games has
When user pressed go back button it open the popup window and user have to select one option

i want to make something like that 
looking for suggestions 
thanks

Comment: Remove `super.onBackPressed();`.

Comment: let me remove the code and let you know thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

From:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Write your code here
    initiatePopupWindow();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```